# Duplicate ID with Fragment on PagerAdapter page

Tags: android, android-fragments

i´m facing a problem with the pageradapter and fragments.

i have a PagerAdapter and on every page i want to put a fragment. on the xml layout of the page, i use this code to add the fragment:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="de.worldcup.android.ui.fragments.GroupTableFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

when i run the application, it crashes when it tries to instanciate the second page of the PagerAdapter (2nd time the instantiateItem method is called) at the line, when i try to  inflate the xml layout of the page.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_activity_item, null);
```

the error:

```
03-15 21:57:34.795: E/AndroidRuntime(6257): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #20: Duplicate id 0x7f050043, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for de.worldcup.android.ui.fragments.GroupTableFragment
```

i looked up the id 0x7f050043 -> it is the @+id/fragment1 id.

any ideas how to fix this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Facing the same problem myself I found this: 
"Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically."
[In the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) In short, create your fragment architecture dynamically to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't think we can not have 2 fragments with the same id in a page.

What i do (but i think it's not the best solution, but it works):
Create one layout for each fragment with a different id.